# Dropdown list goes blank, when form is reopened

Tags: javascript, forms, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a drop-down list in java-script for country's and states.What it does is you pick a country from the list and the state field is populated with a drop-down of states. When I have done this I save the Form with the details. But when i reopen the form , the Country drop-down list goes blank.

The JS , is called in OnLoad event in a CRM Form. I have implemented this in crm-online 2015.
Here is the Java Script code below.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Many Thanks,

```
function LoadCountryField(countryFieldName, stateFieldName) {
    var $countryField = $('#' + countryFieldName);
    if ($countryField.length < 1) return;
    $countryField.hide();
    var selectedCountry = $countryField.val();
    var countryRequirementLevel = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(countryFieldName).getRequiredLevel();
    countryRequirementLevel = countryRequirementLevel == "required" ? 2 : countryRequirementLevel == "recommended" ? 1 : 0;
    var $countryDropdown = generateSelectBox('ddl_' + countryFieldName, countryRequirementLevel, Countries, selectedCountry);
    $('#' + countryFieldName + '_d').append($countryDropdown);
    $countryDropdown.change({ 'countryFieldName': countryFieldName, 'stateFieldName': stateFieldName }, handleCountryChanged);
    document.getElementById('ddl_' + countryFieldName).tabIndex = document.getElementById(countryFieldName).tabIndex;
    LoadStateField(stateFieldName, selectedCountry);
}
// Configures the stateOrProvince field to be a dropdown dependent on the value of the country dropdown. Values are pulled from the Countries object.
function LoadStateField(stateFieldName, selectedCountry) {
    var stateAttr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(stateFieldName);
    var selectedState = stateAttr == null ? "" : stateAttr.getValue();
    var states = getStatesForCountry(selectedCountry);
    var $stateField = $('#' + stateFieldName);
    if (states == null || !$.isArray(states) || states.length < 1) {
        $('#ddl_' + stateFieldName).remove();
        $stateField.show();
        return;
    }
    $stateField.hide();
    var stateRequirementLevel = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(stateFieldName).getRequiredLevel();
    stateRequirementLevel = stateRequirementLevel == "required" ? 2 : stateRequirementLevel == "recommended" ? 1 : 0;
    var $stateDropdown = generateSelectBox('ddl_' + stateFieldName, stateRequirementLevel, states, selectedState);
    var $existingDropdown = $('#ddl_' + stateFieldName);
    if ($existingDropdown.length < 1)
        $('#' + stateFieldName + '_d').append($stateDropdown);
    else
        $existingDropdown.replaceWith($stateDropdown);
    $stateDropdown.change({ 'stateFieldName': stateFieldName }, handleStateChanged);
    $stateDropdown.change();
    document.getElementById('ddl_' + stateFieldName).tabIndex = document.getElementById(stateFieldName).tabIndex;
}
// Finds the states that go with selectedCountry, using the Countries object.
function getStatesForCountry(selectedCountry) {
    for (i in Countries) {
        var country = Countries[i];
        if (selectedCountry == country.name)
            return country.states;
    }
    return [];
}
// Sets the value of the country field to the newly selected value and reconfigures the dependent state dropdown.
function handleCountryChanged(eventData) {
    var stateFieldName = eventData.data.stateFieldName;
    var selectedCountry = setFieldFromDropdown(eventData.data.countryFieldName);
    LoadStateField(stateFieldName, selectedCountry);
}
// Sets the value of the stateOrProvince field to the newly selected value
function handleStateChanged(eventData) {
    setFieldFromDropdown(eventData.data.stateFieldName);
}
// Sets a field's value based on a related dropdown's value
function setFieldFromDropdown(fieldName) {
    var $dropdown = $('#ddl_' + fieldName);
    if ($dropdown.length != 1) return null;
    var selectedValue = $dropdown.find('option:selected:first').val();
    var attr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName);
    if (attr != null) attr.setValue(selectedValue);
    return selectedValue;
}
// Generates a new select box with appropriate attributes for MS CRM 2011.
function generateSelectBox(id, requirementLevel, options, selectedValue) {
    var $ddl = $('<select id="' + id + '" class="ms-crm-SelectBox" req="' + requirementLevel + '" height="4" style="IME-MODE: auto; width: 100%"></select>');
    $ddl.append(jQuery('<option></option').val('').html(''));
    $.each(options, function (i, item) {
        $ddl.append(jQuery('<option></option').val(item.name).html(item.name));
        if (selectedValue == item.name)
            $ddl.find('option:last').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
    return $ddl;
}
```

**** I got it working anyway****
Thanks everyone for their advice and help

Comment: after saving the form, your browser goes refreshed is it?

Comment: Without seeing the Countries object, I'm assuming states is an array of objects, each with a name value?

Comment: @SamR, yes that is correct

Comment: @YogeshJagdale,Yes that must what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is unsupported, if your optionsets contains all the values you can use the dependent optionset MSDN example

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594433.aspx

Comment: Hey , Thanks for that  link,  i have implemented that code , but when i go to my form  a drop-down does not appear in the field i want it too?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are doing, but it looks like you are using unsupported JavaScript which you shouldn't really expect to work.

These sort of calls `getElementById`, this bit where you appear to be `generateSelectBox` adding custom controls, and all that jQuery.

[Supported extensions for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx)

> All interaction with Microsoft Dynamics CRM application pages must
>   only be performed through the methods with the Xrm.Page or Xrm.Utility
>   namespaces documented in the Client-side programming reference.
>   Directly accessing the Document Object Model (DOM) of any Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM application pages is not supported. The use of jQuery in
>   form scripts and commands is not recommended. More information: Use of
>   jQuery

So I would look to replace as much of your non-supported stuff, with supported stuff.

In terms of this blank field on form re-load it's probably because the field wasn't saved to the database. CRM needs to know the field is `dirty` to commit the change. If the field is read-only sometimes this can cause a problem as CRM doesnt expect the field to get `dirty`. I would suggest enabling auditing on the entity to validate if CRM is actually saving the field to the database.